# terraform data source output to file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

I would like to try if terraform data source will be able to place the output to a text file.
I was looking on it online but not able to find any, I plan to perform on getting the load balancer name and after that our automation script will perform aws-cli command and will use the load balancer name taken by the data-source

Comment: You need to know the arn or name of your ALB to use such a data source. So there is not much sense to use data source to get name, if you already know the name. Do you have any code to show what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Technically I would like to get the Classic load balancer name from the terraform output. Load balancer name is auto generated which is formatted to something like "awseb-e-c-AWSEBLoa-2051TEWRHJCNM"

Once I got that name, I will be enabling s3 logging via aws cli  

(classic lb doesn't have option to add s3 bucket for logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CLB name is autogenrated by TF, you can save it in a file using [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file):

```
resource "aws_elb" "clb" {
  availability_zones = ["ap-southeast-2a"]

  listener {
    instance_port     = 8000
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port           = 80
    lb_protocol       = "http"
  }
  
}

resource "local_file" "foo" {
    content     = <<-EOL
    ${aws_elb.clb.name}
    EOL
    filename = "${path.module}/clb_name.txt"
}

output "clb_name" {
  value = aws_elb.clb.name
}
```

But maybe it would be easier to get the output value directly as [json](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/outputs?in=terraform/configuration-language&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS#generate-machine-readable-output):

```
clb_name=$(terraform output -json clb_name | jq -r)
echo ${clb_name}
```

Comment: Load balancer belongs to a beanstalk and created via TF Resource: aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.

Comment: @Lagot Do you think that such an important information should be provided in your question?

Comment: apologies, I was not able to understand your inputs before, I will try your recommendation for creating the local_file